# Unexpected token, expected :

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ternary-operator

I want to work with the ternary-operator but I get the following error message:

" Unexpected token, expected : "

Why is that?

This is my first code:

```
const GetUp = (num) => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
      console.log('Get')
    }
    if (i % 5 === 0) {
      console.log('Up')
    }
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
      console.log('GetUp')
    } else {
      console.log(i)
    }
  }
}
GetUp(200)
```

This is my recent code:

```
const SetRuc = (num) => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) { 
    (i % 3 === 0) ? console.log('Set')
    (i % 5 === 0) ? console.log('Ruc')
    (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) ? console.log('SetRuc') : console.log(i)
  }
}

SetRuc(100)
```

Comment: When you use the ternary operator you have to give it an alternative (after a `:`) like you did in the last one. That's why it's called "ternary": because it has three parts, that is `condition ? true-branch : false-branch`

Comment: And your case is not a really good use of ternary operators, stick to if

Comment: looks like [Fizz Buzz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz#Programming_interviews) under a different name.

Comment: It does look like Fizz Buzz, but at multiples of 5 **and** 3 this logs out "Set Ruc SetRuc" instead of just "SetRuc"

Comment: About your original code (the new one has the same problem), supposing it has to follow the classic rules for fizzbuzz, put the last condition first and use `else if` after the first one.

Comment: Thank Federico! That was the way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `&&` for shothand if without `else`

add semicolumns `;` to let it know that it's the end of the instruction, otherwise it will evaluate the three lines as one instruction.

```js
const SetRuc = (num) => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) { 
    (i % 3 === 0) && console.log('Set');
    (i % 5 === 0) && console.log('Ruc');
    (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) ? console.log('SetRuc') : console.log(i);
  }
}

SetRuc(100)
```

Answer (score 4):

EG this:

```
(i % 3 === 0) ? console.log('Set')
```

provides no `:` option for the `?`.  If you don't want anything to happen in the event that the `?` check is false, you can simply provide an empty object, or `undefined`:

```
(i % 3 === 0) ? console.log('Set') : {}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do anything in case of false result in ternary operator. you can just say something like `statement ? 'expression' : null`

just mention `null` in there. Something like

```js
const SetRuc = (num) => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) { 
    (i % 3 === 0) ? console.log('Set') : null;
    (i % 5 === 0) ? console.log('Ruc') : null;
    (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) ? console.log('SetRuc') : console.log(i);
  }
}

SetRuc(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You misuse the ternary operator, the syntax is:

```
condition ? expr1 : expr1
```

Assuming that `expr1` will be executed if the condition is true, otherwise `expr2` will.

So you may want this:

```
const SetRuc = (num) => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) { 
    (i % 3 === 0) ? console.log('Set') :
    (i % 5 === 0) ? console.log('Ruc') :
    (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) ? console.log('SetRuc') : console.log(i)
  }
}

SetRuc(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const SetRuc = (num) => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) { 
    (i % 3 === 0) ? console.log('Set') :
    (i % 5 === 0) ? console.log('Ruc') :
    (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) ? console.log('SetRuc') : console.log(i)
  }
}

SetRuc(100)
```

you have missed `:` after `console.log('Set')` and `console.log('Ruc')`